# How do you grab a class and add another class in jquery?

Tags: jquery, class

I'm trying to create a snip of code that will add an active class to a page when you navigate to it.  I've used this in the past with ID's and it works fine, but I need classes now so I can use Bootstrap functionality.

```
var mybodyid = $('body').attr('id');
var mynavid = '#nav' + mybodyid;
$(mynavid).attr('id', 'active');
```

I've tried changing everything from 'id' to class and #nav to .nav, but no luck.  I'm guessing I'd change the last line to:

```
$(mynavid).addClass('active');
```

But not sure what to do with lines 1 and 2.

html:

```
<html>
   <body id="home">
     <nav id="navhome">
   </body>
</html>
```

the working code will add an "active" id in addtion to the navhome.  I need all that converted to a class instead of ID.  I mean I know I need to flip all the HTML id's to classes.  I just can't get the JS to add the active class.

Comment: Add your HTML please.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/oqhp4b38/ - hard to see what's wrong with what you've got? Why do you need to do anything with the IDs? Unless there's more HTML that you haven't shown.

Comment: I don't think I'm explaining myself well.  What I'm trying to do is add an active class to my navigation so it changes the nav styling.  I want the class to be added dynamically when you navigate to the page.  My problem is I know how to do this with ID's in jQuery, but I can't make it work using classes.  Because I'm in bootstrap, I need it to be a class otherwise, I'd use what I already have.  Does that make sense?

Comment: do select the answer that worked for you so others having the same issue might also benefit

Answer (score 0):

Since ids are supposed to be unique, theres no need to scope it to the body. Also, don't reassign id. Use  `.addClass`.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `.toggleClass()` if you want to toggle between the classes and `.addClass()` if you want to just add the class.

Let's say I have a `<nav>` that has an ID `my-nav`

```
<nav id="my-nav">
    <ul>
        <li>menu 1 </li>
        <li>menu 2</li>
        <li>menu 3</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

and I want that when I click on a button the nav should have the class `.active`

```
$("#my-nav").toggleClass('active');
```

the above changes to

```
<nav id="my-nav" class="active">
    <ul>
        <li>menu 1 </li>
        <li>menu 2</li>
        <li>menu 3</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

and when I click the button again it should be removed the above will change to

```
<nav id="my-nav">
    <ul>
        <li>menu 1 </li>
        <li>menu 2</li>
        <li>menu 3</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

or if I just want to add class to it

```
$("#my-nav").addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

I was going about this the complete wrong way and trying to force incorrect code into my solution.  Here's what I wanted to do:

When a page loads, I wanted my code to know what page I was on and add a CSS class of "active" to that page's nav link so I could style the link in a way the user knew where they were on the site.

I knew how to do this with CSS ID's, but not with classes.  Here's how to do it:

HTML - note that the links are relative and not absolute:

```
<nav>
   <ul>
     <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
     <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Jquery:

```
function(){
// set active link in nav
// credit: https://www.johnmorrisonline.com/add-active-navigation-class-to-menu-item-based-on-url-using-jquery/
// Get current path and find target link
var path = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop();

// Account for home page with empty path
if (path == '') {
    path = 'index.php';
}
var target = $('nav a[href="' + path + '"]');
// Add active class to target link
target.addClass('active');    
}
```

I'm sure there's a way to make it work with an absolute URL, but this works.